# print the element which is not visible in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor, browser-automation

I often getting the below error message while running test using protractor.

> - Failed: element not visible
>     (Session info: chrome=50.0.2661.102)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459
>     (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.3
>     x86_64)

When my test runs slowly my test is getting passed but sometime my test used to run very faster and due to that i get the above as error message as outcome and not sure which element is not visible or causing the failure.

Is there any way that to print which element is not visible while testing is running too fast? Help me here

Comment: Well doesn't it report the `it` block that fails the test?

Comment: Yes, it block is failed but not the all the lines in 'it' block... protractor processing few lines of code but and later throwing this error.

Comment: Without more of the error message or some of the code, it will be difficult to help you debug the issue.  For example, if an "expect" is failing, I could tell you that you could add some custom error message.  Or if it is an action, such as a click, that fails, I could offer some suggestions for that situation.

Comment: I've marked this as a dup since I think you should be able to solve the problem applying the answers in the linked thread. Let me know if you still experience difficulties. Thanks.

Comment: guys, i am facing this issue when my protractor test is running too fast but when it's running in slow mode i am not facing this issue.